# Function to return all permutations of a vector

Tags: c++

i want a function that takes a vector of integers as input and generate all permutations of that number stored in vector and return a list of vectors containing all the permutation.

```
list<vector<int>> permutations(vector<int> v,int be, list<vector<int>> output)
{

    if(be==v.size()-1)
    {
        output.push_back(v);
    }

    for(int i=be;i<v.size();i++)
    {
        swap(v[be],v[i]);
        permutations(v,be+1,output);
        swap(v[be],v[i]);
    }
    return output;

}
```

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: i just edited it

Answer (score -2):

You might want to take a look at `std::next_permutation` in `<algorithm>`.

Comment: that was useful.But i wanted to implement one.

Comment: Don't [reinvent the wheel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel)